# What determines the value of array.length for a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

Working in Java, suppose I have made a 2D array which is 30 by 50 units, like this:

```
public Array() {
        int[][] array = new int[30][50];
}
```

and then I do this:

```
int rows = array.length;
int columns = array[1].length;
```

why does array.length get me a value of 30? Could the length not also be 50? Similarly, how then does array[1].length work out to be 50?

I have seen this answered elsewhere but I didn't understand the answer (beginner in Java here).

EDIT: This is how it was explained to me before, which I didn't understand. *"when we refer to array.length, we get the length of the larger list, which is 30. When we refer to array[1].length, we get the length of the small list with index 1 in the large list, which is the second small list in the large list. This will have a value of 50."*

Comment: You may want to specify “elsewhere” so we don’t just give you the same incomprehensible answer once again. :-) Even better if you can also tell what it was you didn’t understand about that other answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this simple example

> array[3][5];
>
> array[number_of_row][number_of_column];

`array[3][5]` means 3*5 matrix which is

```
[0,0][0,1][0,2][0,3][0,4]
[1,0][1,1][1,2][1,3][1,4]
[2,0][2,1][2,2][2,3][2,4]
```

> here you can clearly see that 3*5 matrix has 3 rows and 5 columns,
>   that's also means each row has 5 columns. So, array.length means
>   number of rows which is 3 and array[1].length means number of columns
>   in row position 1 which is 5

This logic is same as `array[30][50]`

Comment: Thank you! Other answers were helpful too, but this one was ultra-simple and enabled me to grasp the concept immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite to this, maybe it gets clearer

```
public Array() {
        int[][] array = new int[30][];
        array[0] = new int[50];
        array[1] = new int[50];
        // ... you may use a loop, but to make it explicit
        array[29] = new int[50];
}
```

When you declare an array you MUST indicate at least the first dimension (30). 
In your example all elements of the first dimension holds an array reference to an array with 50 elements.

You can have diferent lengths also:

```
public Array() {
        int[][] array = new int[30][];
        array[0] = new int[5];
        array[1] = new int[7];
        // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know that a 2D array is actually a 1D array with each element in that array is another 1D array.

```
a[0] = [0][1][2][3]
a[1] = [0][1][2][3]
a[2] = [0][1][2][3]
a[3] = [0][1][2][3]
```

so `length` will get the length or the array being called at
**i.e** `a.length` will be the length of `a`, not the length of the array assigned at element 0 or 1 , ...n in `a`

also note the arrays created in each element of the 1D array `a` could be of different length. so calling `a.length` will not be accurate if always returned the length of 1st row i.e: `a[0].length`

```
int a[][] = new int[4][];
a[0] = new int [10];
a[1] = new int [7];
a[2] = new int [11];
a[3] = new int [30];
```